# Are Brussels Sprouts and Brussel Sprouts the same dish?

Tags: brussels-sprouts

Because one implies "Sprouts from Brussels" and the other implies the vegetable that children stereotypically hate.

Comment: @Juhasz no answers in comments, please, including half-answers.

Comment: @downvote Why did someone downvote this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The veggie is correctly spelled brussels sprouts.  I assume spelling it without the "s" is just an error or being unaware of the proper spelling.  Wikipedia suggests the vegetable got its name because of its popularity in Brussels, Belgium.  So, in a sense, they are "sprouts from Brussels."

Comment: “Brussel sprouts” is an example of [rebracketing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebracketing).

Comment: And (certainly in British English) the two versions are pronounced identically so it's a very natural change. Degemination across a word boundary, like the term *prime minister*: https://improveyouraccent.co.uk/double-consonants-in-english-geminates/

Comment: @moscafj Thank you for your answer sir!  I was working on a menu and it was driving me crazy, so I had to ask.

Comment: The Dutch spelling of the Belgium city is Brussel, without the S at the end, so maybe someone used that instead of the English spelling. But in the Dutch of the Netherlands the vegetable does not have the name of the city in its name.

Comment: What do Dutch people call brussels sprouts?

Comment: @FuzzyChef Going by the Wikipedia entry, it's *spruitkool* which I think breaks down as 'sprout cabbage': https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spruitkool